# Why can't I access my custom signal under the SignalName subclass when trying to emit it?

Tags: c#, godot, godot-4

I have recently decided to start learning Godot after previously having experience with Unity, and am continuing with C# as my primary scripting language. While everything else regarding signals seems to be working, I find myself struggling to emit custom signals, as they are not defined within the `SignalName` subclass as the [Godot Documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/c_sharp/c_sharp_signals.html#signal-emission) claims.

Complete script:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class Icon : Sprite2D
{
    [Signal] 
    public delegate void RotatingToggledEventHandler(bool isRotating);

    bool rotating = true;

    // Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
    public override void _Ready()
    {
    }

    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
        if(rotating) 
        {
            Rotate((float) delta);
        }
    }

    public override void _Input(InputEvent @event) 
    {
        if(@event.IsActionPressed("ui_accept")) 
        {
            rotating = !rotating;
        }
        StringName rotatingToggled = "RotatingToggled";
        EmitSignal(SignalName.RotatingToggled);
    }
}
```

`SignalName` subclass:

```
public class SignalName : Node2D.SignalName
{
      public static readonly StringName FrameChanged;
      public static readonly StringName TextureChanged;

      public SignalName();
}
```

The event which is to be triggered by the signal emit:

```
using Godot;
using System;

public partial class main : Node2D
{
    // Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
    public override void _Process(double delta)
    {
    }
    private void OnIconRotatingToggled(bool isRotating) 
    {
        GD.Print("hello there");
        if(isRotating)
        {
            GetNode<Label>("RotatingStatus").Text = "Rotating: active";
        }
        else 
        {
            GetNode<Label>("RotatingStatus").Text = "Rotating: inactive";
        }
    }
}
```

The receiver method is already linked to `main.cs`.
[image]

The error:
[image]

Error code is `CS0117`.

ADDITIONAL INFO: I am using VS code as my text editor, and have the C#, godot-tools, and C# tools for Godot extensions enabled, and am connected to the GDScript language server. All other facets of scripting seem to be working. For context, I am trying to reconstruct [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZg2qgtPy6U&ab_channel=BurgZergArcade) in C# to teach myself Godot signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to emit a signal is an `StringName`. You should be able to confirm that by looking at the definition of `EmitSignal`.

An `StringName` is an [internal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) string in Godot engine.

---

`SignalName`, on the other hand, is a convenient way to get the `StringName` you need to pass to reference the signal. And it should be generated automatically.

It is not relevant if the `StringName` comes from `SignalName` or not, what matter is if the `StringName` is correct. Consequently it is not necessary to subclass `SignalName`.

*Do not confuse `StringName` and `SignalName`.*

---

Thus, if the signal you want is not in `SignalName`, you can still use `EmitSignal`, like this:

```
EmitSignal("RotatingToggled");
```

*This is also the way you would use it if you added signal dynamically during execution (with `AddUserSignal`).*

Here, the `string` will be implicitly converted to an `StringName`. You could do that conversion yourself. You could also extract the value to a variable. And if you want to reuse it, perhaps promote said variable to a readonly field. And if you really want, move that field to another class - which you need to reference correctly - and said class could perhaps extend `SignalName` - which is completely irrelevant - … None of that is necessary for this to work.

Comment: Thank you! This seemed to do the trick. I wish the Godot documentation was clearer on this, but maybe I should just actually read the method descriptions.